# How to set the same function of Linux iptables in Windows?

Tags: windows

In Linux, we can use iptables for setting forward an other limits:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23:2300]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9090 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT # accept Internet 10.8.0.x
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 10.8.0.0/24 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT # forward to intranet 192.168.1.x
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited  
COMMIT
```

But how can this be set in the Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

... not. The firewall in windows is just a firewall. Routing and forwarding is done by the windows router (RRAS).